# How to step through a for loop every x amount of times

Tags: c#, algorithm, console-application

I have a for loop of varying length depending on items in the database, I'm trying to figure out how to divide the loop further into every 5 loops print an output and then jump to a new line without duplicating the result.

What I've been able to think of, is that it may be a modulo that I need to implement.

c#

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        int v = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < 20; i++){
            if(i % 5 == 0){
                Console.WriteLine(v);
                v = v + 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

    }
}
```

What I am getting is:

```
1
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
2
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
3
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
4
Done
Done
Done
Done
Done
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Done
6
7
8
9
10
Done
11
12
13
14
15
Done
16
17
18
19
20
Done
```

Comment: if you only want the "done" do happen on the % 5 case... maybe move the `Console.WriteLine("Done")` inside the `if`?

Comment: Just print "Done" inside the if and the number outside? I mean, swap them...

Comment: MoreLinq's `Batch` may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the loop you want:

```
for(int i=0; i < 20; i++){
    if(i % 5 == 0){
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
    Console.WriteLine((i + 1));
}

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you, I can't believe such simple logic escaped me. Hopefully it will work as intended in my application.

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output in the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity according to the OP this does give the desired output. You didn't however.

Comment: @PeterMeadley - The OP specifically shows what he wants in the question where he says "What I'm trying to achieve is".

Comment: @Enigmativity The OP is the first comment in this comment chain.

Comment: @Enigmativity is right, it should be `(i+1)%5` or loop bounds should be 1 and 20. It does not give the desired output.

Comment: @PeterMeadley - The question trumps the comments and he also said "Hopefully it will work as intended in my application". I don't think the OP actually tested the code.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - This is exactly what the down-vote system is for. And it's what every user should be doing regardless of their rep level.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't think so, it is for worst cases, not for silly mistakes, typos if the answer is correct.

Comment: The actual output is irrelevant, it’s the stepping through every x amount of times that I was looking for. @DontVoteMeDown answered my query with what I was looking for first. The actual application is a lot more comprehensive than a 1st year college coding challenge.

Comment: @Bazilby - Stack Overflow exists to create a library of good quality questions and answers for the entire community. The answer you pick should answer the question you posted. If you have a different criteria in mind then your question should be changed to reflect that criteria. I have no problem with this being your prefered answer, but it should be clear that it does answer the question.

Comment: Noted, I'm still relatively new to this website and a little unfamiliar with the type of culture it encourages. It was my fault for not checking the code block to ensure the variable initialized to the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

It gives:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Done
6
7
8
9
10
Done
11
12
13
14
15
Done
16
17
18
19
20
Done
```

Comment: So, my code is succinct and it outputs precisely what the OP requires, why the down-vote?

Comment: Just so you know, it's not me. I appreciate any help I can get. It was just a simple program to work out the logic, the actual application is a little grander in design, using asp:literals and dynamic html creation for this section specifically. I just couldn't remember how to step through a for loop every x amount of times. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in your case

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int v = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(v);
        v = v + 1;
        if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `int v` is now irrelevant in this code as it always has the same value as `i`.

Comment: In this code it has same value as int i but int v can be any data I have put here just to make code simpler

Comment: I would argue that it's making the code more complicated. It's a definite source for bugs in the future.

Comment: Yeah you are right sir if we pretend that int v is some other datatype and other data is stored in it then it would be more easy to understand, in other case we can use int i instead of int v for simplicity of code

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to **step through** the loop every x time I thought something like this might be helpful:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        int v = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 20){
            for(int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++){
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            v++;
        }

    }
}
```

I don't know what do you want to do with `v` but here it is and has the same value as `v` in your code.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for what you are trying to do.

```
for( auto i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i+1} ");
    if((i%5) == 0)
    {
          Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice spot on `++i` but be aware that OP's real code could need the original zero-based index

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output in the question.

Comment: Yes because if you go back in history, that's what the OP had posted when the answer was written. Thank you for down-voting.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - No, I checked the original version of the question. The OP didn't know how to format the question's text, but the requirement hadn't changed.